# How to extract function name python regex

Tags: python, regex

Hello I am trying to extract the function name in python using Regex however I am new to Python and nothing seems to be working for me. For example: if i have a string "def myFunction(s): ...." I want to just return myFunction

```
import re 
def extractName(s):
    string = []
    regexp = re.compile(r"\s*(def)\s+\([^\)]*\)\s*{?\s*")
    for m in regexp.finditer(s):
       string += [m.group()]
    return string
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current version?

Comment: It is returning nothing in the list when I test it.

Comment: It's a good idea to check your regex in a special service like this one: https://regex101.com/r/pUajdb/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: You want the name `myFunction` from "...def myFunction(s):..."

I find something missing in your regex and the way it is structured.

`\s*(def)\s+\([^\)]*\)\s*{?\s*`

Lets look at it step by step:

1. `\s*`: match to zero or more white spaces.
2. `(def)`: match to the word def.
3. `\s+`: match to one or more white spaces.
4. `\([^\)]*\)`: match to balanced ()
5. `\s*`: match to zero or more white spaces.
   After that pretty much doesn't matter if you are going for just the name of the function. **You are not matching the exact thing you want out of the regex**.

You can try this regex if you are interested in doing it by regex:

`\s*(def)\s([a-zA-Z]*)\([a-zA-z]*\)`

Now the way I have structured the regex, you will get `def myFunction(s)` in group0, `def` in group1 and `myFunction` in group2. So you can use the following code to get you result:

```
import re
def extractName(s):
    string = ""
    regexp = re.compile(r"(def)\s([a-zA-Z]*)\([a-zA-z]*\)")
    for m in regexp.finditer(s):
        string += m.group(2)
    return string
```

You can check your regex live by going on this [site](https://regex101.com/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: That regex doesn't catch most python function. Use this instead: `(def)\s(\w+)\([a-zA-Z0-9_:\[\]=, ]*\)` It matches functions with underlines and numbers, and type hints on their arguments.